# Watch promise (resource) changes in Angular 1.2.0+

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm using $resource for loading array of items in my controller:

```
$scope.items = api.items.query();
```

The `$scope.items` is now promise. Once it is resolved, it contains array of items. Than I have some methods, manipulating the items, for example:

```
// template
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <a href="" ng-click="doSomething(item)">Do it!</a>
</div>

// controller:
$scope.doSomething = function(item) {
    item.$doSomething(); // the items 
};
```

Here I would like to watch changes in `$scope.items`, so it gets notified once any of the item changes . I tried this:

```
$scope.$watch($scope.items, function() {
    console.log('changed');
});
```

but this doesn't work - it is not triggered after the doSomething changes the object. Neither helps the third `objectEquality` parameter. I also tried `$watchCollection`, but with no luck.

I found this worked for a short period of time - since Angular 1.2.rc2 the promises unwraping was introduced (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3503), but it was removed in 1.2.0 (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4158).

So is there now (current stable is Angular 1.2.4) any way how to do this?

Thanks!

P.S.: This was also discussed in this question: [AngularJS - binding/watching a function which returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188074/angularjs-binding-watching-a-function-which-returns-a-promise), but this is not applicable for 1.2.0+.

Comment: Maybe because of this? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577

Comment: I know about it, but: "This feature has been deprecated and if absolutely needed, it can be reenabled during transitional period" - and I would prefer not to rely on deprecated feature...

Comment: I just stacked with the same issue. You could try $scope.$watch($scope.items.$resolved, function() {});

Comment: You could iterate over items and add watches for each item.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the Promise to $scope.items, wait until the promise resolves then assign the result to $scope.items.

```
api.items.query().then(function(itemsQueryResults){
  $scope.items = itemsQueryResults;
});
```

When the items property is updated Angular will run a digest cycle as normal and your ng-repeat will populate.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1.4.6, I was able to solve this by adding a third parameter to $watch. Note that I also had to reference the scope property by string name:

```
$scope.$watch('items', function() {
    console.log('changed');
}, true);
```