# watch on directive scope property does not work as intended

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with a own angular directive I wrote, which takes a promise as a parameter. This "promise-parameter" can be undefined in the beginning and is watched, so that changed to it should be seen in the watch function.

I got two different versions of the directive ("loader").

The first one works:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkw43/23/

The second one does not:
http://jsfiddle.net/rkw43/25/

```
            $scope.watch('promise', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                console.log("New Value: ");
                console.log(newValue); // NEW VALUE equals "promise" and not the query.promise from parent scope, why?
```

As stated in the comment of the second version, "newVal" in the watch function of the loader-direactive is always equal to "promise", but it should be thew new promise-object from the parent scope.

Why doesnt this work? What is wrong here? Im trying to figure it out for hours...

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449428/watch-promise-resource-changes-in-angular-1-2-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's a typo in your second fiddle

`$scope.watch('promise', function(newValue, oldValue) {`

should be

`$scope.$watch('promise', function(newValue, oldValue) {`

1. In your controller, you're attaching deferred object instead of promise. So either do:

`$scope.query = deferred.promise` in your click handler or do

`$scope.promise.promise` in `execute` function.

Comment: Thats it, I used the native watch function and therefore didnt trigger angularjs. Big Thanks :)